# What is the easiest way to publish React PWA to the play store?

Tags: reactjs, google-play, progressive-web-apps

i tried with Bubblewrap (https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/bubblewrap/tree/master/packages/cli) but it throws the following error:
[image] Although this is the correct path!

is there another way to do it?
i'm confused, please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use https://pwabuilder.com, it uses Bubblewrap to create an APK for you.